# Find the value of a third order circulant type determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, determinant, symmetric-polynomials

To calculate the value of the determinant\begin{pmatrix}
(b+c)^2  &c^2  &b^2 \\ 
c^2 &(c+a)^2  &a^2 \\ 
b^2 &a^2&(a+b)^2
\end{pmatrix} .
I multiplied R1,R2,R3 by a²,b²,c² respectively and then used the operations R1=R1-R2,R2=R2-R3,R3=R3-R1 which got me a zero valued determinant eventually. The correct answer given is 2(bc+ca+ab)². What's wrong with the row Operations that I used? Is there any other suitable Operations?

Comment: What if $a=0$? The determinant would then be $2b^3c^3$, but by multiplying the first row by zero you’ve zeroed out the entire determinant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's $$\prod_{cyc}(a+b)^2+2a^2b^2c^2-\sum_{cyc}a^4(b+c)^2=$$
$$=2\sum_{cyc}(a^3b^3+3a^3b^2c+3a^3c^2b+2a^2b^2c^2)=2(ab+ac+bc)^3.$$

I used the following.

$$\prod_{cyc}(a+b)=\sum_{cyc}\left(a^2b+a^2c+\frac{2}{3}abc\right),$$
$$\left(\sum_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c)\right)^2=\sum_{cyc}(a^4b^2+a^4c^2+2a^3b^3+2a^4bc+2a^3b^2c+2a^3c^2b+2a^2b^2c^2)$$ and
$$\sum_{cyc}a^4(b+c)^2=\sum_{cyc}(a^4b^2+a^4c^2+2a^4bc).$$

Comment: Is there a way using elementary operations without actually expanding the determinant?

Comment: I did not think about this. I like to work with polynomials and I saw this solution immediately.

Comment: That helps. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome!